# How can I populate content from a facebook page using Opengraph without using a facebook app ? is that possible?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph, php-5.3

So I'm told to do this not so clear  project where I am supposed to create a facebook page and populate it with content from another facebook page using opengraph . For this project , I do not have to use a facebook app... How can I achieve this in PHP using Opengraph ??

```
    1.     Create a Facebook fan page and populate content from Facebook.com/TomClancyAuthor (six pieces will be sufficient for this exercise)

    2.       Set the ‘Age Restriction’ to ‘people 17 and over’

    3.       Using Open Graph, consume and display the content of the age restricted Facebook fan page on a website

Note: Do NOT use a Facebook app for this project
```

Comment: have you checked out the facebook documentation?

Comment: Facebook document only shows when you're using an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a contradiction, you can't use the 'Open Graph' without a 'Facebook App', as you need an app ID to access anything via Facebook's API unless that information is completely public and needs no authentication.

A page which is restricted by age or geographic location can only be accessed using an access token from a user that meets those requirements, which means you need such a user to grant your app ID access to access the API on their behalf.

I suspect whoever used the phrase 'Facebook App' in the question doesn't understand how the Facebook API works, or is asking you to avoid a specific way of implementing this without clarifying what that method is

Comment: That's what I thought , you need a facebook ID , etc ... Do you know populate content from fan page to another facebook fan page I created using Opengraph ??? I dont see help for this on the documentation

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ - you can read the posts from one page, then repost the same content to another